# Как исправить ошибку "Недопустимое имя столбца ..." в запросе SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Имеется запрос:

```
SELECT ПК.КодП, ПК.КодК, ПК.Совм, Н.УчебныйГ, ПК.Ставок, 
    IIF((select ЗначениеЛогическое from НагПарамС where Код = 27) = 0, 0, 1) AS Коэф, 
    IIF(Коэф = 0, 
        SUM(ISNULL(Н.НагрузкаАуд, 0) + ISNULL(Н.НагрузкаДр, 0)) * Н.НормКоэф, 
        SUM(ISNULL(Н.НагрузкаАуд, 0)) + SUM(ISNULL(Н.НагрузкаДр, 0)) * Н.НормКоэф
       ) AS ЧасовЧ 
FROM dbo.ПреподКаф AS ПК INNER JOIN dbo.Нагрузка AS Н ON ПК.Код = Н.КодД 
WHERE Н.УчебныйГ = '2018-2019' AND Н.УчебныйГ = ПК.УчебныйГ AND (Н.КодК = '11') 
GROUP BY ПК.КодП, ПК.КодК, ПК.Совм, Н.УчебныйГ, ПК.Ставок 
HAVING(ЧасовЧ > ПК.Ставок * 900 ) 
ORDER BY ПК.КодК, Н.УчебныйГ, ЧасовЧ
```

При его выполнении возникает 2 ошибки:

```
Сообщение 207, уровень 16, состояние 1, строка 10
Недопустимое имя столбца "ЧасовЧ".
Сообщение 207, уровень 16, состояние 1, строка 3
Недопустимое имя столбца "Коэф".
```

В интернете видел примеры запросов, где таким же ключевым словом "as" объявлялся столбец и затем беспроблемно использовался в конструкции Having. Что исправить в запросе, чтобы и у меня работало? Использую SQL Server 18.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему введением переменной, работающий запрос выглядит так:

```
        DECLARE @temp int; 
        SET @temp = (select ЗначениеЛогическое from НагрузкаПарамС where Код = 27);
        SELECT ПК.КодП, ПК.КодК, ПК.Совм, Н.УчебныйГ, ПК.Ставок,  
                IIF(@temp = 0, 
                         SUM(ISNULL(Н.НагрузкаАуд, 0) + ISNULL(Н.НагрузкаДр, 0)) * Н.НормКоэф, 
                         SUM(ISNULL(Н.НагрузкаАуд, 0)) + SUM(ISNULL(Н.НагрузкаДр, 0)) * Н.НормКоэф
           ) AS ЧасовЧ 
        FROM dbo.ПреподКаф AS ПК INNER JOIN dbo.Нагрузка AS Н ON ПК.Код = Н.КодД 
        WHERE Н.УчебныйГ = '2018-2019' AND Н.УчебныйГ = ПК.УчебныйГ AND (Н.КодК = '11') 
        GROUP BY ПК.КодП, ПК.КодК, ПК.Совм, Н.УчебныйГ, ПК.Ставок, Н.НормКоэф 
        HAVING(IIF(@temp = 0, 
                   SUM(ISNULL(Н.НагрузкаАуд, 0) + ISNULL(Н.НагрузкаДр, 0)) * Н.НормКоэф, 
                   SUM(ISNULL(Н.НагрузкаАуд, 0)) + SUM(ISNULL(Н.НагрузкаДр, 0)) * Н.НормКоэф
           ) > ПК.Ставок * 900 ) 
        ORDER BY ПК.КодК, Н.УчебныйГ, ЧасовЧ
```

Answer (score 1):

У вас слишком хитрый запрос, вы всё хотите за раз выполнить.

`IIF(Коэф = 0`, - объявляется и тут же используется. `ЧасовЧ` такая же история. Придется подготовить подзапрос либо использовать как есть

примеры смотрите [тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-having-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) и [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14048672/why-cant-i-use-an-alias-for-an-aggregate-in-a-having-clause)